# Write variable containing large text with \n to a file with common shell interpreters. How do you do it?

Tags: shell, files, string

Environment: linux shell or better, ash shell in busybox (example system: Openwrt).

Given a string variable with **large** text `"${a}"` constructed in this way:

```
for index in $(seq 1 40000); do #it is 40000 for a reason, it helps if you want to reproduce the error on your system.
   a="${a}""\n""word ${index}"
done
```

and given the fact that trying to use this variable as argument for common command produce an error, for example:

```
echo "${a}" #fails
awk -v VAR_A="${a}" '<program>' #fails
```

(the failures are due: http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/ )

How do you write such a variable to a text file, possibly using only simple commands and not sed/awk/perl/other powerful interpreter.

Ideally the text file should look like:

```
word 1
word 2
word 3
...
```

and not like:

```
word 1\nword 2\nword 3\n...
```

**Update1:** Someone asks "Why you cannot change the script that produce the variable `$a`?". Because i cannot due to, let's say, lack of authorization ("*the script was working until today, so you can fix only the printing part*"). So `$a` and its format is given, i can only find a way to print it to a file.

**Update2:** Using the suggested "here docs" solve most of the problems but still i have the content printed in one line. Maybe is my config?

Comment: Are you requesting to pass the results of $a (the echo statement) into a text file?

Comment: How is `echo` failing. `echo` is usually built-in and should not trigger the E2BIG error.

Comment: I didn't know either, just try it. In the end is reasonable, everything is finite.

Comment: And yes I get $a in the format defined by the for and I need to output it.

Comment: @PierfrancescoPierQRAiello - I don't think you do need to store it in `$a` at all. Consider: `for i in 1 2 3 4 5 ; do echo "$i" ; done >file`. But doing `for i in $(seq $num) ; do echo word $i; done` is redundant because you can just do `seq -s'word' $num`

Comment: That is true, but, that is due my crap English sorry, it is like that you get `$a`, you want to print it to a file but you cannot change it. You receive this variable and your goal is printing it out. So your solution is ok but it is referring to another problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can make a [here document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04) and use `cat`:

```
$ cat <<EOT >output
$a
EOT
$ wc -l output
40000
```

I don't know exactly how powerful your Busybox's `ash` is (it's configurable), but that should work anywhere, even with no builtins at all. It expands the variable value into a quasi-file, which is then given to `cat`, rather than putting the value itself into the command line.

---

Since you seem to have literal `"\n"` in your string that you want to get rid of, you can also use string replacement during parameter subsitution. This *can* be configured out of Busybox's `ash`, in which case you'll have to go to `sed`. If you do have this (non-POSIX) extension, you can use `${var//\\\n/$NEWLINE}`:

```
$ busybox ash
$ foo="x\ny\nz"
$ echo "$foo"
x\ny\nz
$ NEWLINE="
"
$ echo "${foo//\\\n/$NEWLINE}"
x
y
z
```

This is the same syntax [as Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion-1); `${var/pattern/replacement}`, where `pattern` is global if it starts with `/`. It seems your `ash` has a lot configured out of it, so this might not be there at all. In that case you're probably going to have to go with `sed`, although I guess judicious use of `IFS` and `read` would let you work around that and reconstruct a correct string.

Comment: not really answering the question - the problem is passing large amounts of data on command line.

Comment: @peterph - which this does. this is a file descriptor - not an argument.

Comment: Yup, it works but still i have "\n" in the output. Namely `# cat output | wc -w` returns `40001` ; while `# cat output | wc -l` returns `1`

Comment: @PierfrancescoPierQRAiello: You *may* be able to use string replacement (see edit), but if that isn't part of your minimal `ash` you'll probably have to go to `sed`.

Comment: many thanks! Would have been enough to have some hints, while I got a long explanation that required time!

Answer (score 1):

```
busybox seq -s'
word ' 4000 | 
sed '/000/w /dev/fd/2' |  
wc -l
```

#### OUTPUT

```
word 1000
word 2000
word 3000
word 4000
4000
```

You should just be able to use `busybox`'s builtin `seq` and specify `word` as a separator. Then you can `>redirect` it to a file if you wish. In the above example I split out to `sed` just so you could get an idea of the output without having to look at 4000 lines - but they were all printed. If your `busybox` does not support this, [upgrade](http://www.busybox.net/live_bbox/live_bbox.html).

So basically all you need for that whole `$a` thing is:

```
busybox seq -s'
word ' $MAX_INCREMENT >$TO_FILE
```

Comment: not really answering the question - the problem is passing large amounts of data on command line.

Comment: @peterph : Here's the question I read. *How do you write such a variable to a text file, possibly using only simple commands and not sed/awk/perl/other powerful interpreter[?]* The answer I propose lies in generating and writing the variable's value at once, using only simple commands... etc.

Comment: @PierfrancescoPierQRAiello - please do this instead of the other thing I used to have here just in case you're doing that one. It is essentially the same, byut far simpler. Just in case you're doing the other thing, that is.

Comment: thanks Mikeserv, but the variable is given. I cannot improve the generation of it (else peterph would have already replied). You get this huge stuff and you need to write it to a file.

Comment: @PierfrancescoPierQRAiello - then you need to use the heredoc like the Michael Homer suggests. Still, I cannot understand how it can be given - it has to get into the shell somehow. Either it is generated by iterating as you demonstrate and can be replaced like I demo above, or it is sourced from a file, in which case you do `busybox ash ./file >oufile`. You shouldn't ever have to store information of that size in a single shell variable ever. You would probably have better luck with the argument array as well, like `set -- "$@" "$a"` once every iteration - to avoid a single long string.

Comment: @PierfrancescoPierQRAiello - also, nearly everything @peterph told you before was incorrect. If it *is* an ARG_MAX problem then it can only be because you're *not* using the shell's builtin utilities. You may fare much better with `busybox echo "$a"` for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the hints @mikeserv . The point is, let's say, that i cannot change the code that produce `$a` for some "high order call". Then i'm stuck with this problem. I'm just allowed to print the value of the variable to a file.

Comment: @PierfrancescoPierQRAiello Ok. Then the heredocument will work. It's a good solution, though I still don't understand how you get it in the first place. Oh well, I'll let it be...